# NSwag generated output for nested types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mediator, nswag

Is there a way to configure NSwag such that nested types are generated using the parent class name instead of just the child class name?

Traditionally, you would write something like this:

```
    public class SomeRequestHandler { /* Implementation omitted for brevity */ }
    public class SomeRequest { /* Implementation omitted for brevity */ }
    public class SomeDTO { /* Implementation omitted for brevity */ }
```

Following naming conventions makes it apparent that the Handler receives a Request and returns a DTO, where all SOME-prefixed classes belong together. NSwag has no trouble generating the client code using these conventions.

What I'm trying to accomplish is writing my classes as follows:

```
    public class OtherRequestHandler
    {
        public class Request {}
        public class DTO {}
    }
```

On the API, differentiating between requests is done by specifying the handler for each request, ie. `typeof(OtherRequestHandler.Request)` or `typeof(OtherRequestHandler.DTO)`, but NSwag generates the inner classes without the names from the outer parent classes. This leads to NSwag trying to resolve duplicate class names with numbers, giving me DTO1, DTO2, Request1, Request2, etc.

So, is there a way to have NSwag generate it such that it looks like `OtherRequestHandler.Request`, or alternatively `OtherRequestHandlerRequest`, or `OtherRequest`?